# Launching an Android Activity from a different package?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

So what I'm trying to do is combine two separate android packages that I've created. The first package is for the main menu, and the second package is for another activity I've created. I will be adding more activities later.

What I'm doing is opening the activity from a Navigation Drawer I've created. I made the second package into a library and sort of got the Java coding to work(read:theres no indication of errors). Here's the code I'm using:

```
case 3:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.expandablelistviewdemo.MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            this.startActivity(intent);
              break;
```

For whatever reason, the application crashes when I click on that option in the Navigation Drawer. I'm not really sure where to go from here. I have a feeling that I'm not supposed to use "this", but I'm not sure what else I would put there. Any other information needed I can post.

LogCat:

```
[2015-03-17 22:16:32 - NavigationDrawer] ------------------------------
[2015-03-17 22:16:32 - NavigationDrawer] Android Launch!
[2015-03-17 22:16:32 - NavigationDrawer] adb is running normally.
[2015-03-17 22:16:32 - NavigationDrawer] Performing com.example.navigationdrawer.MainActivity activity launch
[2015-03-17 22:16:35 - NavigationDrawer] Uploading NavigationDrawer.apk onto device '2e03c4ed'
[2015-03-17 22:16:35 - NavigationDrawer] Installing NavigationDrawer.apk...
[2015-03-17 22:16:41 - NavigationDrawer] Success!
[2015-03-17 22:16:41 - NavigationDrawer] Starting activity com.example.navigationdrawer.MainActivity on device 2e03c4ed
[2015-03-17 22:16:42 - NavigationDrawer] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.navigationdrawer/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Why does LogCat say your app crashed?

Comment: Have you added `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: It doesn't give any indication that it crashed in the LogCat

Comment: No I have not, how would I do that, I don't see any option to add this particular library?

Comment: @GurpalRattu that thing you posted is not from LogCat.

Comment: Oh sorry, the only thing the LogCat says is Device Disconnected

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.expandablelistviewdemo.MAINACTIVITY");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

In Manifest File

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.testsample.Pkg.Test"
        android:label="JS" >

    </activity>
```

In First activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, com.example.testsample.Pkg.Test.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This working for me. I tried this now. You might have some other problem. This code is working in my machine while testing.

Comment: I tried with sample app and is working fine for me. You might have done something wrong in some other place caused the issue

Comment: What is the label JS?

Answer (score 0):

1.See whether you have mention MainActivity in your Manifest file or not.
2.Check navigation item get clicked or not printing log message.
3.Instead this try with MainActivity.this.
4.If this is not an activity then try with passing context.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working on my android app:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setClassName(this,"com.example.expandablelistviewdemo.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Also edit your manifest.xml file with your jumped package name.

Comment: <activity
        android:name="com.example.testsample.Pkg.Test"
        android:label="JS" >

    </activity>